# Tests are failing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest, react-test-renderer

I am trying to run Jest test runner on my react project and I am using third-party UI library called semantic-ui-react. When I write simple tests and run then, they are running successfully but when I import any component from semantic-ui-react and test my custom component, I am getting the below error.

Test suite failed to run

```
/xxx/node_modules/semantic-ui-react/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from 'semantic-ui-react';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

** dependency versions: **

```
"babel-jest": "^21.0.0",
"jest": "^21.0.1",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel the babel-jest is not transforming new es6 feature 'export'. If so, please help me transform such keywords

Comment: It's not supposed to transform it, it ignores node_modules by default. This is specific to your setup. There's no /index.js in any legit package version, see https://unpkg.com/browse/semantic-ui-react@2.0.0/ . And it should import /dist/commonjs/index.js in Jest, it has no `export` and won't cause this problem.

Comment: @EstusFlask, Thanks. It worked after resolving the way I was importing module.